# Form Upload with request->getParameter value equals null wil crash the web app

Tags: symfony1

I think I found a weird problem in Symfony.

Here's my upload case form:

```
<?php

class UploadCaseForm extends sfForm {
    public function configure()
     {
        $this->setWidgets ( array ('Documents' => new sfWidgetFormInputFile ( ) ));
        $this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('UploadCase[%s]');
        $this->setValidators(array(
        'Documents'=>new sfValidatorFile ()
        ));



    }
}
?>
```

And the action class is this:

```
public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request) {

    if ($this->getRequest ()->getMethod () == sfRequest::GET) {
        $this->form = new UploadCaseForm ( );
    } else if ($this->getRequest ()->getMethod () == sfRequest::POST) {
        $this->form->bind ($request->getParameters('UploadCase'), $request->getFiles ( 'UploadCase' ) );


    }

}
```

I would expect that after I upload a file, `$request->getParameter('UploadCase')` should return a NULL, but not crashing the web application. Instead the web app crashed.

Anything that I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [a bug, I think](http://forum.symfony-project.org/index.php/t/19946/). The bug is because `$request->getParameter('UploadCase')` has only 1 file upload, no other fields. So the below statement will return null.

```
($request->getParameter('UploadCase'));
```

And this will cause the statement

```
$this->form->bind ($request->getParameters('UploadCase'), $request->getFiles ( 'UploadCase' ) );
```

to crash like there is no tomorrow.